# MySQL general query log analysis

Tags: mysql

Currently performing software archeology on an old-ish installation of MySQL 5.6. I have a few months of [MySQL general query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-log.html), and would like to do a statistics on what queries are being run by whom how often, as various "undocumented" automata from all over have been set up to access said database. Do I have to go all Perl on this or is there a ready-made analysis tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I wrote a Perl script to do this. Not perfect but it does its job.

Available at GitHub [mysql56_query_log_analysis.pl](https://github.com/dtonhofer/muh_linux_tomfoolery/blob/master/mysql56_query_log_analysis.pl)

Note that the MySQL 5.6 general query log has a different format than the MySQL 5.7 query log, so another script will be needed for 5.7.